# Trade agreement details in Total War

Tags: warhammer-total-war

When negotiating a trade agreement the game says

> The more resources you own, the higher the chance this faction will
>   sign the treaty

[image]

First of all this is not true because Tomb Kings won't be using many of my resources, so they don't matter.
More importantly, this suggests that the other side benefits from my having more  resources.

1. So does that mean the income display under "Their Demands" is the income they will be getting?
2. So if I have more resources other parties get more income?

That seems strange to me, I should be the beneficiary from having more resources.

Comment: Just a note, Tomb Kings is actually one race that "Use" trading resources. Most faction only permits building a unique building in the region and boosting trade. Tomb Kings actually need certain resource to make most of their craftable artefacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI can be a bit confusing here.

On the left side (your side), the UI shows you how much money you earn from the trade and which resources you export to the trade partner. The right side shows how much money they earn and which resources you import from them.

Think of it as "I gain this much money for exporting this and that".

So, in your example, you'll earn 620 gold per turn and no resources, while Arkhan gains 110 gold and all those resources on your side.

Note: The Tomb Kings are the only faction, which actually uses resources for their mortuary cult mechanic (edit: a similar mechanic called forging has been added for dwarves  in Warhammer 2 only since posting this answer originally). For all other factions, resources only increase the value of trade agreements. So, you are generally correct in the assumption, that those resources aren't actually used by the trade partner, however not in this specific example.

I also have never seen any evidence, that having more resources to trade increases the likelihood of someone accepting a trade agreement. The diplomacy system is very obfuscated here. I've seen factions with +200 relations refuse a profitable trade for them and factions with +5 relations accept the same trade.

Comment: When I said the resources weren't used, I meant that when you hover over the income there's no amount near most of the resources I have available. Meaning he won't be using those resources.

Comment: @MrFox The amount doesn't matter. It only matters whether you have the resource or you don't. All the amount does is increase the trade value of that resource.

Comment: @MrFox: When you hover over the resources when you have no excess resources (everything is already being traded to other partners), you'll see that it tells you that your available resources will be distributed among your trade partners. This means that the amount of resources a partner receives can change when you make other trade treaties later on. Any time your resource count changes, the amount of resources traded to partners is affected, but this happens automatically, as does the income gained from said trade treaty.